# Pandas: How can I label ticks on x-axis with months from Jan to Dec and limit the range on the y-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is what my csv file looks like:

[image]

I skipped the first 4 rows because they contained no data. Once at row 5 I used pandas to get the data line by line. This part I think I got but I want to be able to organize the data for column 'Date' so that on the x-axis they appear as Jan, Feb, March... but not sure how this is done with Pandas as pd.

I also want to be able to label the y-axis with 'Evapotranspiration (inches)' and have a title at the top that reads 'Eden_7'. So far there is a ledgend in the top right corner that I don't want there. Not sure how to remove. Lastly I want the threshold for the y-axis range to be from 1 to 7 not 1 to 8.

Here is the code I have working so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('1541544819_et.csv', skiprows=4)



dataset[['Date', '2A300 Potential evapotranspiration (millimeters)']].set_index('Date').plot(figsize=(15, 8))
```

And so far this works almost perfect except for the details mentioned above.

Here is what the graph looks like:
[image]

This is what I am trying to have my final graph look like. Just the bottom one:
[image]

Updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('1541544819_et.csv', skiprows=4)


plt.xticks(range(11), ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Nov','Dec'], rotation=45)



ax = df.plot()
ax.set_ylabel("Evapotranspiration (inches)")
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi Josh, please have a look at [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Anyway you can find an answer on this [post](https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/05/24/pandas-bar-plot-with-formatted-dates.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to play with the format of the dates - you can look at [strptime and strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) or look into [MatPlotLib formatting for axis stuff](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html?highlight=date%20formatting). You can also plot the dataframe directly in MatPlotLib and have additional options to fix the legend labeling and control more parameters. Here's a [starting guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py).

Comment: Thanks! Okay dataframe seems to be the way to go with Matplotlib. How would I upload a csv into a dataframe assign it first column to the x-axis and the second column to the y-axis?

Comment: to plot dfs that way: plt.plot(df['a'], df['b']) and to read in the csv look into pd.read_excel and pd.read_csv

Comment: Thanks. I did that but now by x-axis is just a bar of black I think it's all the year-month-day data. How would I have that read as Jan, Dec, Mar? 
Here is what it looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/s7wLNzx

Comment: I'd look into setting the tick range, setting label stuff...investigate axis options in MatPlotLib, including the time formatting stuff.

Comment: Okay just did that. Now my problem is merging the xticks and the data together into one. here is what that looks like: https://imgur.com/a/UMhLum4